# How to keep custom listview items when they are out of screen?

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, adapter

I am trying to design a menu like this:

[image]

It almost works, however there is a problem. The menu works fine at start, but after scrolling down and up again, the items are gone and downloaded again and it takes a little time. Is there a way to set a number of elements to create at start and keep them from disappearing?

Here is my code:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    String headers[];
    String image_urls[];

    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;
    ListView mylistview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        menuItems = new ArrayList<MyMenuItem>();
        headers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.header_names);
        image_urls = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_urls);


        for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
            MyMenuItem item = new MyMenuItem(headers[i], image_urls[i]);
            menuItems.add(item);
        }

        mylistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        MenuAdapter adapter = new MenuAdapter(this, menuItems);
        mylistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        mylistview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}




public class MyMenuItem {

    private String item_header;
    private String item_image_url;

    public MyMenuItem(String item_header, String item_image_url){
        this.item_header=item_header;
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }

    public String getItem_header(){
        return item_header;
    }

    public void setItem_header(String item_header){
        this.item_header=item_header;
    }

    public String getItem_image_url(){
        return item_image_url;
    }

    public void setItem_image_url(String item_image_url){
        this.item_image_url=item_image_url;
    }


}






public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    List<MyMenuItem> menuItems;

    MenuAdapter(Context context, List<MyMenuItem> menuItems) {
        this.context = context;
        this.menuItems = menuItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return menuItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return menuItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return menuItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivMenu;
        TextView tvMenuHeader;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.tvMenuHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvMenuHeader);
            holder.ivMenu = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMenuItem);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        MyMenuItem row_pos = menuItems.get(position);

        Picasso.with(context)
                .load(row_pos.getItem_image_url())
             //   .placeholder(R.drawable.empty)
             //   .error(R.drawable.error)
                .into(holder.ivMenu);

        holder.tvMenuHeader.setText(row_pos.getItem_header());

        Log.e("Test", "headers:" + row_pos.getItem_header());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should **download the elements only ONCE** (if not existing) to a folder, before loading the ListView (from the saved ones in the folder). Now it is fast. Forgot to mention: **use a ProgressBar**, while loading in the AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can implement lazy loading with some sort of caching of images or whatever you are downloading...

Answer (score 0):

You say the images are donwloaded, i assume that the images are coming from internet. Implement a custom cache for http download or download and store the images in one place before you use